# Clear alerts for remote APN

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, alert, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that receives remote APN notifications while the app is in the background.  If the notification style is banners, it works perfectly.

However, when the notification style is alerts and receives 10 APNs, the user must dismiss subsequent alert boxes after selecting "launch" for the first alert.

Is there any way to clear the alerts after the application is launched?

I have tried the following in applicationDidBecomeActive: and applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
[application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

But it doesn't work.  Anybody else have this problem?

Also, I know this is possible because WhatsApp is able to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't push notifications not show up as alerts while the application which they represent is in the foreground? It seems to me that, once the user hits View on one of the notifications, your application should silently swallow the rest of the notifications.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that when the application is in background when remote APNs are received.  I assumed the notifications should be swallowed, but it isn't the case here...

Answer (score 0):

I understand clearly what you want to achieve in this topic. However, your code won't work.

```
[application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

'cancelAllLocalNotifications' only applies to Local Notifications - which are scheduled by an application and delivered by iOS on the same device.

As discussed by apple, APNs handles the remote notification when your app is in background. If your app is in foreground or is currently active, your delegate will manage the notification.

---

Try handling the notification in [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidReceiveRemoteNotification%3a)

Here's a sample:
(you can manage the payload from here):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    

}
```

---

You can also check whether your app is in foreground or that your app is active:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        // app active.
    }
    else {
        // app not active
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I figured it was only for local notifications; but I was getting desperate.  Is there any way to clear the rest of the incoming alerts?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm...I don't think that notification alerts will continue popping-up when the app is on foreground. (not quite sure, though). Anyhow, try the code I've edited on my answer.